# Migrating to Spring Boot - 'Error build callback listeners; entity was already processed'

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to migrate a Spring 4 with Hibernate 4 webapp running on tomcat 7 and JDK 1.6 to Spring Boot 1.2. I created an `Application.java` class that loads my XML application context and has a `main` method to start. However, I get the following exception now, and I have no clue what could be the reason or how to debug it:

```
2014-12-30 13:25:07 INFO [main] LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2014-12-30 13:25:10 WARN [main] AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: 
Error build callback listeners; entity [com.company.domain.message.data.impl.BicycleDataMessageImpl was already processed
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950)
    at com.traficon.tmsng.server.application.Application.main(Application.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Error build callback listeners; entity [com.traficon.domain.message.data.impl.BicycleDataMessageImpl was already processed
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.CallbackRegistryImpl.addEntityCallbacks(CallbackRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.LegacyCallbackProcessor.processCallbacksForEntity(LegacyCallbackProcessor.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.spi.JpaIntegrator.integrate(JpaIntegrator.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:852)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:845)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:844)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Work with the framework... You are probably configuring everything yourself in XML instead of using Spring Boot to do the configuration for you. I suspect that that leads to processing your entities twice.

Comment: What kind of bean could be in my XML that leads to this double processing? I would like to pinpoint more. It is impossible to replace all XML config at this point as the application is huge.

Comment: The bean that does the setup for the `EntityManagerFactory` so probably the `LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean`. If you are using native hibernate disable the `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration`.

Comment: Also I would recommend replacing what you can with the auto config features of Spring Boot as that will really simplify your application. At the moment it doesn't add much but being able to have an embedded tomcat.

Comment: How do I disable the `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration` ? I know it does not bring much at the moment, but I would replace the XML gradually with Java Config. Being able to start my app from my IDE would already be great.

Comment: The `@EnableAutoConfiguration` has an `exclude` property. You can put the auto config classes in there you want to skip for now. I wasn't talking about replacing xml by java config I was talking about removing config because Spring Boot already does that (like `DataSource`, Jpa, transactions, security, ...).